# Security implications when setting the discard option in /etc/crypttab

Tags: disk-encryption

Setting the **discard** option in **/etc/crypttab** has security implications.

From the [man page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html):

```
Allow discard requests to be passed through the encrypted block device. 
This improves performance on SSD storage but has security implications.
```

**Q:** What are the security implications if this option is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A discard request, aka "TRIM", puts part of a solid-state drive into an "unused, ready to write" state.  An attacker can use this to figure out which parts of the drive are empty, something they couldn't figure out if those sections contained encrypted empty space.

Comment: That can be used for example to determine what filesystem is used on the drive. See [here](http://asalor.blogspot.de/2011/08/trim-dm-crypt-problems.html) for a detailed explanation about it.